# jQuery AJAX url path

Tags: ajax, jquery

This is my jQuery AJAX code and this javascript file is placed in

```
C:\workspace\search-ui\search-ui\src\main\webapp\themes\client\javascript\agile.js
```

And I want to call proxy.jsp file from this jQuery AJAX, and my jsp file is in

```
C:\workspace\search-ui\search-ui\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\pages
```

so what will be the url field of AJAX call.. Any suggestions will be appreciated..

This AJAX jquery code is in Javascript file called agile.js and I have to call proxy.jsp page from this javascript file

```
var on_show_info = function() {
    var outOfDomainAjaxCall = search_metadata + current_doc_info.id;
    alert(outOfDomainAjaxCall);
                request_meta_info = $.ajax({
                url: "proxy.jsp?url=" + outOfDomainAjaxCall,
                type: 'GET',
                success: on_get_metadata,
                error: on_get_metadata_error

        });
    };
```

Comment: where is this ajax being called?

Comment: @Neal, locally on the eclipse.. And if it works fine then I have to deploy on server..

Comment: whats the file location?

Comment: @Neal, I have written file location in my questions.. And which location u r talkign about..

Comment: OF THE FILE THAT  IS DOING THE AJAX.... not the jsp or the jquery.js file

Comment: @Neal,  AJAX call is in that javascript file..

Comment: @Neal, AJAX call is in that same javascript file..
`C:\workspace\agilesearch-ui\agilesearch-ui\src\main\webapp\themes\client\javascript\agile.js`

Comment: What file is this being included in (with script tags etc) in the jsp file?

Comment: I have updated the question.. let me know if you don't understand now..

Comment: @Raihan - that said nothing. In what file do u have the script tags that calls the .js file?

Comment: @Neal, I am calling js file from another jsp file(search.jsp) that is in `C:\workspace\agilesearch-ui\agilesearch-ui\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\pages\search.jsp`.. Something clear now??

Comment: Raihan -- yes. see my answer.

Comment: I just updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling the script from: `C:\workspace\agilesearch-ui\agilesearch-ui\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\pages\search.jsp`

And the page you are trying to reach is: `C:\workspace\agilesearch-ui\agilesearch-ui\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\pages\proxy.jsp`

Change your code to:

```
var on_show_info_agile = function() {
            //alert("aa");
var outOfDomainAjaxCall = search_agile_metadata + current_doc_info.id;
alert(outOfDomainAjaxCall);
            request_meta_info = $.ajax({
            url: "proxy.jsp",
            data: "url=" + outOfDomainAjaxCall, //put the data here
            type: 'GET',
            success: on_get_metadata_agile,
            error: on_get_metadata_agile_error

    });



};
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
"../../../WEB-INF/pages/proxy.jsp?url=" + outOfDomainAjaxCall
```

Comment: @YonoRan, I tried with this.. still m getting error..  `<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 404</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /WEB-INF/pages/proxy.jsp. Reason:
<pre>    NOT_FOUND</pre></p><hr /><i><small>Powered by Jetty://</small></i><br/>                                                `

Comment: and your sure that the locations of the files are just the way you specified them up top?  so where is the function being called from? you say that the js file is in the directory that you specified, but where is the file that calling the ajax call?

Comment: Trying to ascertain where the ajax call is being made from. If something has to be calling the ajax call... so where is that file? what directory? not the js file... the actual file making the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

```
".../WEB-INF/pages" + outOfDomainAjaxCall,
            type: 'GET',
            success: on_get_metadata_agile,
            error: on_get_metadata_agile_error
```